# POST-REDIRECT-GET with decrypted streams rather than html docs

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-views

I am using on-disk encryption to protect some client data. After logging in, the users must provide another symmetric key in order to decrypt the file off disk:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Template
from my_lib import decrypt_file
import os
import magic

@login_required
def secret_stuff(request):
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        return render_to_response('reenter_key.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    password = request.POST.get('symmetric_key')
    encrypted_file = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'secret.enc')
    byte_string = decrypt_file(password, encrypted_file)
    file_type = magic.from_buffer(byte_string)
    if b'data' in file_type:
        return render_to_response('bad_key.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

     decrypted = Template(byte_string)
     return HttpResponse(decrypted.render(RequestContext(request)))
```

This design is annoying for users because page reloads are post requests. How can this be avoided without saving the decrypted file to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying that you want to avoid forcing the user to re-enter the key every time they access the data?

That means you have to save the key in a place where it can be accessed by multiple processes. The usual way to save per-user data in Django is to use the [sessions framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). The problem is that you won't want the key to be any more accessible than the decrypted file would be (so presumably not in the database or on disk).

You could use the [cache backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions) for sessions (or just skip sessions and cache it manually if you're already using sessions for something else). As noted in the documentation, though, the local-memory cache is inappropriate.

You could use memcached or redis, though of course the key will be vulnerable to anyone who has access to the cache. And if the cache engine is running on a separate, external server you have to worry about sending the key over the network (though using SSL is also a possibility).

In the end, there's a trade-off between security and the convenience of your users, so you'll have to decide what attack vectors you're worried about and what degree of security is good enough.